# Retorno personalizado em WEB API

Tags: web-service, asp.net-web-api

Boa tarde.

Gostaria de saber se existe algum padrão ou boa prática (independente da linguagem de programação), para construção de Web API que permitam a personalização do conteúdo da resposta, por parte do cliente (usuário desta API).

Exemplo:
Uma API web com o seguinte recurso: **http://aplicacao/api/clientes/100**

que retornaria um JSON no padrão:

```
{
    "id": "100",
    "nome": "nome do cliente 100",
    "endereco": "endereço completo do cliente 100"
}
```

Agora imaginemos que em um determinado cliente desta API, exista uma funcionalidade para montar uma tabela de clientes, onde seja necessário listar apenas os atributos "id" e "nome".

Uma solução hipotética seria criar um outro método na API que retornasse apenas os dados necessários. Desta forma, evitaria-se a transferência desnenessária dos dados (neste caso o campo "endereco").

Porém, não parece ser uma boa ideia ficar entupindo a API com métodos tão específicos, de acordo com as necessidades dos clientes desta API.

Diante deste cenário, a pergunta então é, existe algum padrão para personalização deste retorno por parte do cliente?

Comment: Isso é ASP.NET WebAPI, né?

Comment: vc pode passar na requisição os nomes dos campos que vc quer retorno por ex http://aplicacao/api/clientes/100/id:nome:endereco onde o : é o separador

Comment: Da onde você tirou isso? @JasarOrion

Comment: he uma ideia q eu t deipara alterar a requisição na sua api

Answer (score 2):

Geralmente as API retornam bastante coisa, e muitas delas nós não usamos.
Você pode entupir sua API de parâmetros ou pode simplesmente retornar tudo.
Não vejo problema em retornar dados desnecessários, a não ser que seja algo que o cliente realmente não possa ver.

Comment: O problema é o consumo desnecessário de recursos do servidor e de dados. E a piora do desempenho.
Imagine que você tenha um objeto que dentre outras propriedades, tenha uma lista de imagens. E que você precisa apenas gerar uma lista deste objeto utilizando as propriedades "id" e "nome". Então você faz uma requisição para a API e uma quantidade enorme de dados é pesquisada no banco e retornada na requisição desnecessariamente.

Answer (score 1):

Se existe algum padrão eu não sei, mas isto é bem simples de implementar. Você só precisa ter bem definido como vai saber quando decidir retornar um ou outro formato.

Veja um exemplo, onde valido se o usuário logado é do tipo `UsuarioComum`, caso sim, são retornados todos os dados da entidade, caso contrário, são retornados apenas `Id` e `Nome`.

```cs
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{       
    if(usuarioLogado.Tipo == TipoUsuario.UsuarioComum)
    {
        var retorno = _db.Clientes.Find(id)
                                  .Select(c => new 
                                               {
                                                    c.Id,
                                                    c.Nome,
                                                    c.Endereco
                                               });
        return Ok(retorno);
    }

    var retorno = _db.Clientes.Find(id)
                              .Select(c => new 
                                           {
                                               c.Id,
                                               c.Nome
                                           });
    return Ok(retorno);

}
```

Comment: jbueno, obrigado pela resposta, porém não é sempre que teremos estas regras definidas do lado do servidor.

Comment: Você deveria ter dito isso na pergunta, aí eu nem teria escrito a resposta dessa forma. De qualquer maneira, pesquise sobre OData.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado jbueno, é exatamento o que estou precisando.

Comment: Encontrei o seguinte artigo explicando sobre o assunto: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-select-expand-and-value

Comment: Show. Esse é o melhor lugar pra aprender sobre. Bons estudos! Vou tentar atualizar minha resposta pra te dar um panorama geral, mas, por via do tempo curto, não sei se consigo ainda hoje.